# Merging/Joining datasets

Tags: python

I have two datasets (`csv` files), A and B for simplicity. 
`A` contains all the products; `B` contains only unique values of products (no duplicates). 
A sample of `A` is:

```
Date          All_products
01/07/2020          tv
01/07/2020        radio
04/07/2020         pen
04/07/2020         pen
04/07/2020       notebook
04/08/2020         pen
...                ...
04/10/2020        radio
```

I have approx. `29000` rows

A sample of `B` is:

```
Unique_products     Col1    Col2 ...

tv                  300      24
radio               120      12
pen                 1000      7
notebook            60        2
...                   ....
```

I have only unique value from `A` and same other columns `(Col1, Col2,...Col 5)`. 
Number of rows approx `2000`.

I would like to merge the datasets in order to have for each product the values that come from dataset `B` (csv file):

```
 Date          All_products         Col1        Col2
01/07/2020          tv               300         24
01/07/2020        radio              120         12
04/07/2020         pen              1000          7
04/07/2020         pen              1000          7 
04/07/2020       notebook             60          2
04/08/2020         pen              1000          7
...                ...                ...        ...
04/10/2020        radio              120         12
```

Could you please tell me how to generate the output above? Should I merge/join tables? If yes, how could I do it?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Do you have a library you're using already to load and process your datasets? Or do you want to solve this problem with only basic Python objects? Do you just want to print out the table output you show, or is your intent to save it to a new CSV file at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = pd.read_csv('a.txt', sep=" ")
```

[image]

```
b = pd.read_csv('b.txt', sep=" ")
b.rename(columns={'Unique_products':'All_products'}, inplace=True)
```

[image]

```
ab = pd.merge(a, b, on='All_products', how='left')
```

[image]